# Are mysql records able to be accessed through terminal navigation?

Tags: linux, terminal

By terminal navigation I mean being able to `cd` and `ls` through the file system

From what I gather, all data storages have a file system (example: ext4) to manage your datastore. A terminal can expose filesystem access by letting you navigate through the various folders of your computer through the use of commands such as `ls` and `cd`. This must mean that, in order to save data to disk, mysql needs to save the data to the file system. Which then begs the question - can access my sql records by `'cd'`ing into the right directory?

Comment: Note that all the data in a database is stored in a small handful of files, so you need to enter the data file to see tables and rows. since the file is binary, its generally not possible to do so, but someone may have tried to abstract the data out as a tree. why they would do so however is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

1) If all you want to know is can I?  Yes, there is a [fuse module for MySQL](http://mysqlfs.sourceforge.net).

2) If what you want to do is something useful, the answer is, probably not.  There is a big difference between what you can do in a filesystem (cd, pwd, open/read/write/delete) and what you can do in a DB.  You have many many more operators in SQL than you have in any filesystem. You may be able to `cat` a table, but what if it has binary data? What would you do for an Index? Or a View? Or a join?

Yes, a filesystem is a DB, but not all DBs are filesystems. You're basically saying "a car is an automobile. My Toyota Prius should be able to tow 20,000 pounds since I know (some) automobiles can do that".

Also, MySQL saves data to a blob on disk, it does not use much of any fancy "filesystem is a DB" tools available.  Some DBs would rather not have a filesystem - I've heard of Oracle DBs going directly to a raw partition (essentially like swap) to get the "filesystem is a DB" overhead out of the way.